# Angular 10 Formly + material vertical multicheckbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-formly

I want to create formly multicheckbox with a vertical view. But when I created a field like this I still display it same line.

```
    {
  label: 'Zgody marketingowe',
  fields: [
    {
      key: 'agreementIds',
      type: 'multicheckbox',
      className: 'flex-1',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'zgody!!!!!!',
        required: false,
        style: "background: green;",
        options: [
          {
            key: 'zgodaNr1',
            value: 1
          },
          {
            key: 'zgodaNr2',
            value: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a solution for you. To achieve `multicheckbox` with a vertical view you can try `ul` and `li` tags like below=>

Here is the code below [Stackblitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwvq1k?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.html).

**TS:**

```
export class CheckboxOverviewExample {
 
  subtasks=[
      {id:1, name: 'Primary', completed: false, color: 'primary'},
      {id:2,name: 'Accent', completed: false, color: 'accent'},
      {id:3,name: 'Warn', completed: false, color: 'warn'}
    ];
  updateAllComplete(data:any){
  console.log(data);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="example-list-section">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let subtask of subtasks">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="subtask.completed"
                      [color]="subtask.color" 
                      (ngModelChange)="updateAllComplete(subtask)">
          {{subtask.name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using formly instead of FormGroup